# How to use net.tcp port sharing in Azure Service Fabric

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric, net.tcp, tcpportsharing

I want to deploy a WCF service that utilizes net.tcp port sharing. When running on a normal Windows Server, I make sure that the *NET.TCP port sharing service* is enabled and running and my application launches without any issues.

When switching to Azure Service Fabric, this service is not running on the node and my application cannot start. How do I make sure that when I deploy my application to a node that the node has WCF.s NET.TCP port sharing service installed and enabled?

Comment: Are you seeing any specific errors when deploying? What about in Service Fabric Explorer? Does this work on a local instance of service fabric and not when publishing to Azure?

Comment: The problem is that the service isnt't running, so an exception is thrown that the NET.TCP port sharing service is disabled. For now, I enable the service in C# code but it's not very elegant. I would rather provision the VM so the service is running.

Comment: I found the following which might help

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-connect-and-communicate-with-services#reliable-services-built-in-communication-api-options

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-services-communication-wcf